# Rgnuplot in linux: plot window does not appear

Tags: linux, r, plot, gnuplot

I have installed Rgnuplot in R version 2.15.1 on Debian Stable Linux. I ran following code from example given on page: https://github.com/cran/Rgnuplot/blob/master/demo/hello1.R

```
require(Rgnuplot)
#"Hello World!" - text on legend
#Initialize the gnuplot handle
h1<-gp.init()
#set output to a postscript file
#gp.cmd(h1,'set terminal postscript eps color;set output "helloworld1.eps"')
#label the x and y axis
gp.set.xlabel(h1, 'x')
gp.set.ylabel(h1, 'y')
#set plot style to "lines"
gp.setstyle(h1, 'lines')
#plot sin(x) and add a legend
gp.plot.equation(h1,'sin(x)','Hello World!')
```

But plot window does not appear. I tried other examples also but no plot window appears. How can I solve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you run the code? If I paste it in an interactive session, it shows the plot window, but not if I run it from a file with `R --no-save < hello1.R` (But I have R 3.1.0 on Debian sid). Please try also to uncomment the line `gp.cmd ...` so see if plotting to a file works.

Comment: I found out the reason. Please see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that gnuplot-x11 was not installed. After installing it the plot window is appearing all right with correct graphs.

For the developers of Rgnuplot: it would be helpful if an error/warning is shown when gnuplot-x11 is not installed. Presently, the commands are accepted without any error/warning but no plot window appears and users have no clue about the problem.